# Background dinamico com CSS? Como fazer?

Tags: javascript, css, react

eu tenho uma dúvida, é possível a troca de background conforme uma condição?

Exemplo:

```js
function A() {
  if (meuArray.length === 7) {
    eu quero background verde
  } else {
    background azul
  }
}
```

A principio eu estou fazendo um jogo de cartas chamado Black Jack ou 21 no Brasil, e até agora não achei uma forma viável de por background ou um CSS no array que contém os valores de cada carta.

Alguem teria uma dica ou de como fazer? Obrigado

Comment: Sim. Utilize `document.querySelector("#your-element").style.background = "#F00"` ou `document.querySelector("#your-element").style.setProperty("background", "url('your-image.png')")`

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde você pode usar os números da cartas e montar um array com elas e quando for usa-las apenas chamar a posição do array.

exemplo:

```
var cartas = [];
cartas[0] = '#f333dd';
cartas[1] = '#ffffff';
cartas[2] = '#000000';
cartas[3] = '#f23f5d';
```

....

```
$(element).attr('style','background-color:' + cartas[2] + '');
```

Espero que esse código te ajude.